# On macOS, where should I create link to "set default" scripts in multiple version scenario?

Tags: macos, shell

I've written a script by name set_my_product_xx_as_default. (where xx is version number)

I want to allow user to install multiple versions of my product, also want script set_my_product_xx_as_default for various versions to be made available from prompt right away for all the users.

If I try to create link to this script(at /Applications/my_product_dir) from /usr/local/bin then it is read-only FS, therefore won't allow with SIP enabled(I suppose). Where should I place the link or links?

Comment: You can also turn your script into application that will reside inside /Applications - take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/netbeans-make-macos-installer-beautiful-again/ - I know this is not exactly what you are looking for, but maybe you decide to use apps instead of scripts.

Comment: Also, take a look at SIP here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899 (I guess, /usr/local/bin should be fine)

Comment: You are right @Oo.oO , the mac that is given to me has write protected space mounted over /usr/local/bin. Thanks for that link